# Can the same LinkedList be accessed in multiple classes?

Tags: java, linked-list, jframe

Hear me out, I want to create a singly-linked list that will take in properties depending on what the user typed, this is from one frame.

However, I want to be able to use the same linked list in another frame (or class) so I can show it for display. Is it possible that the data stored in the linked-list will be saved and accessed somewhere else?

Comment: I don't know anything about jframe, but if you want the same LinkedList to be accessible from another instance of the **same** class, then you have to define it as `static`. This means the LinkedList object will be common to each instance of that class.

Comment: @HyperZ static state is almost always the wrong solution and leads to hard to maintain and test code.  It's certainly not necessary to share state.

Comment: @Voo I don't understand his question 100% , I told about `static` because it could **maybe** be what he is looking for. But I agree there must be a cleaner way to achieve this.

Comment: Im not trying to access the LinkedList in the same class,since I will be using it in a new jFrame, which I assume means a new class. Sorry if I was not clear. Basically, I have a new Link created in one class, however after pressing a jbutton, I will be taken to another JFrame in which I want to be able to access the LinkedList and everything in it. Thanks HyperZ and Voo though for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wrapper class, let's say `MyList` and use static method to update/ retrieve the list objects.

```
public final class MyList {

    private static final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    private MyList() {
    }

    public static void add(String thing) {
        list.add(thing);
    }
}
```

you can use it like `MyList.add("string")` anywhere. you can also add static methods for `delete`, `get`, `count` etc.

Comment: I want to use a LinkList in this situation and not an arrayList. Thank you though.

Comment: You can change ArrayList to LinkedList. Everything else stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Variables can have various modifiers:

private and public would be two. If a variable, for example a LinkedList, is private, then only the class in which this variable is can access it (directly).

If you want a variable to be accessible from other objects, you have to either declare it public - or create a public "setter" method for it, for example...

```
private LinkedList myLinkedList;

public LinkedList getMyLinkedList() {
   return myLinkedList;
}
```

This way, every class who knows an object of the class you have declares your variable in, can access it. In your case, you could access `myJFrame.getmyLinkedList();` everywhere where you know your JFrame.

Of course, this is not the only way, you could do this the other way around and set your LinkedList into an Object if you create it. For example, when you are inside your JFrame, you could call...

`new MyOtherclass( myLinkedList );`

...which would call the Constructor your "MyOtherclass" with the LinkedList as an argument. Of course you would have to write this Constructor, for example...

```
public MyOtherclass(LinkedList aLinkedList) {
 super();
 this.myLinkedList = aLinkedList;
}
```

Comment: thanks florian,sorry but my terminology is bad so I got a bit of what you were saying but not everything. Your right, I did create a public class called linkedlist and so it can be an object. However, I didnt comprehend your explanation. Could you please explain it again.THANKS

Comment: Wait, so your saying if my LinkedList is an object, and I have a another JFrame I want to access the LinkedList,all I do is pass the linkedList as an argument in that new JFrame class and I should be able to access the LinkedList and all the elements inside it?

Comment: (Almost) everything in Java is an object. So, yes, if you want to do something with an object (that was created in class A) in class B, you somehow have to "give" it to class B, either via Constructor or getter/setter.

Comment: Quick question though since your still here hopefully, what if data was added to the link list and the program closes. If we open the program again will the link list be empty or will it still contain the same date. Long story short, I'm treating link list as a database and would like to know if data is still available. Thanks so much. (In aware of MySQL, however I want to try it with link list if possible)

Comment: As soon as the program closes, the Java Virtual Machine terminates and will be completely gone from memory. So, if you start it again, the list will be empty again.